# Magento EE banners rotation with full page caching on

Tags: caching, magento, content-management-system, banner, fpc

A brief description of what I do:
- create 2 new test banners
- add a Banner Rotator to a cms page, either using the Insert Widget button or via a XML update in the Design tab, selecting the 2 test banners and rotating them as series, random or shuffle
- view the elected page in the browser, refresh

Only the first banner will be displayed.
If FPC is off instead, the banners will rotate as expected.
Is it a bug, or what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The way full page cache works is that it utilizes placeholders for various data that is NOT supposed to be cached with the full page. Examples would include the mini cart, recently viewed products, etc. These separate items are cached and updated separately usually using a cache key that is made of a descriptive name plus the user's session ID.

This file: /app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/cache.xml shows the placeholders.

A good example for what you need to do is here: /app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Container/Viewedproducts.php

Comment: Banners already have their own file in the PageCache/Model/Container folder with very similar code, but I don't see what it is about CatalogProductItem or Viewedproducts.php that makes them refresh on every page load, but Banners are still cached.